# Create a Json Object from an ajax returned Json Object

Tags: json

This json object is returned via ajax.

```
[{"fiscal_year":2.012,"groupName":"Group1","Quantity":31666,"Revenue":"18,700,482.83"},
{"fiscal_year":2.013,"groupName":"Group1","Quantity":9264,"Revenue":"8003393.585"},
{"fiscal_year":2.014,"groupName":"Group1","Quantity":2483,"Revenue":"3,413,629.16"},
{"fiscal_year":2.012,"groupName":"Group2","Quantity":0,"Revenue":"3,055,922.45"},
{"fiscal_year":2.013,"groupName":"Group2","Quantity":0.00E+00,"Revenue":"3,916,824.84"},
{"fiscal_year":2.014,"groupName":"Group2","Quantity":0,"Revenue":"3,444,182.80"}
]
```

I need to modify it and save it as another json object so that I can display the years in columns.

```
 $.ajax({
  url: 'static/doc/sample.json',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'JSON',
  success: function(data){
    var obj = [];
    var business_group_nm = '';
    $.each(data,function(key,value){

      if(business_group_nm!=value.groupName){
        obj.push({
          "groupName": value.groupName,
          "year":[value.fiscal_year:{
               "Quantity":value.Quantity,
               "Revenue":value.Revenue
          }];
        });

      }else{
        obj["year"].push(value.fiscal_year:{
               "Quantity":value.Quantity,
               "Revenue":value.Revenue
          }];
        });

      }
      business_group_nm = value.business_group_nm;
    });
```

Final json object I want it to be:

```
[
    {
        "business_group_nm": "Group1",
        "year": [
            {
                "2012": {
                    "Quantity": "31666",
                    "Revenue": "18,700,482.83"
                }
            },
            {
                "2013": {
                    "Quantity": "31666",
                    "Revenue": "18,700,482.83"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "business_group_nm": "Group2",
        "year": [
            {
                "2012": {
                    "Quantity": "31666",
                    "Revenue": "18,700,482.83"
                }
            },
            {
                "2013": {
                    "Quantity": "31666",
                    "Revenue": "18,700,482.83"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
];
```

But I got an error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :'

```
"year":[value.fiscal_year:{
              "Quantity":value.Quantity,
              "Revenue":value.Revenue
}];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
obj["year"].push(value.fiscal_year:{
       "Quantity":value.Quantity,
       "Revenue":value.Revenue
  }];
});
```

That just makes no sense, you can not use that kind of syntax “outside” of an actual object notation. And using `.push` is also wrong here, that is a method of Array, not for objects.

Something along the following lines should work to add a new property to `obj["year"]`, using the fiscal_year value as property name and assign it an object as value:

```
obj["year"][value.fiscal_year] = {
  "Quantity":value.Quantity,
  "Revenue":value.Revenue
};
```

**Edit:** In this place,

```
"year":[value.fiscal_year:{
  "Quantity":value.Quantity,
  "Revenue":value.Revenue
}];
```

you are using the square brackets, which mean *array*, not *object* – but an array does not have any such “associative” keys. If you want this to be an object as well, then use curly braces here as well.

Comment: Hi CBroe, Thank you for your replying.  I made the change as you suggested.

However the error is here: 

"year":[value.fiscal_year:{
              "Quantity":value.Quantity,
              "Revenue":value.Revenue
}];

What's wrong with the json object inside 'year' array?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi CBroe, as you see, the key 'year' is an array of object

{
     "business_group_nm": "Enterprise2",
     "year": [
         {
             "2012": {
                 "Quantity": "31666",
                 "Revenue": "18,700,482.83"
             }
         },
         {
             "2013": {
                 "Quantity": "31666",
                 "Revenue": "18,700,482.83"
             }
         }
     ]
 }

So if I change square bracket to curly braces, it becomes invalid json.

I tested the object here: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Well that you have to create an object inside the array: `[{…}]`.